# How to fix invalid double in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have data coming from ESP32 in this format: number,number,number and I am trying to print it in text in flutter but I am getting invalid double.

I really read the other answers but could not figure it out. this is my code:

```
String _dataParser(List<int> dataFromDevice) {
    return utf8.decode(dataFromDevice);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
            Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: StreamBuilder<List<int>>(  **// I am getting the error here**
                    stream: stream,
                    builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active ||
                                   snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                temperature = -1;
                                speed = -1;
                                pressure = -1;
                                flow = -1;
                            }
                            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                var currentValue = _dataParser(snapshot.data);
                                var sensorData = currentValue.split(",");
                                // get the temperature
                                if (sensorData[0] == "nan") {
                                  temperature = -2;
                                }
                                temperature = double.parse('$sensorData[0]');
                                // get the speed
                                if (sensorData[1] == "nan") {
                                  speed = -2;
                                }
                                speed = double.parse('$sensorData[1]');
                                // get the pressure
                                if (sensorData[2] == "nan") {
                                  pressure = -2;
                                }
                                pressure = double.parse('$sensorData[2]');
                            } else {
                                temperature = -3;
                                speed = -3;
                                pressure = -3;
                                flow = -3;
                            }
                        }
                        return Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                                Column(
                                    children: [
                                        const Text('Temperature'),
                                        Text('$temperature'),
                                    ],
                                ),
                                Column(
                                    children: [
                                        const Text('Speed'),
                                        Text('$speed'),
                                    ],
                                ),
                                Column(
                                    children: [
                                        const Text('Pressure'),
                                        Text('$pressure'),
                                  ] ,
                                ),
                                Column(
                                    children: [
                                        const Text('Flow'),
                                        Text('$flow'),
                                    ],
                                ),
                            ],
                        );
                    }
                ),
            ),
        ],
    );
}
```

the problem is with this line:

> temperature = double.parse('$sensorData[0]');

the exception is:

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════
> The following FormatException was
> thrown building StreamBuilder<List>(dirty, state:
> _StreamBuilderBaseState<List, AsyncSnapshot<List>>#67513): Invalid double [][0] The relevant error-causing widget was
> StreamBuilder<List> lib\componants\device_data.dart:139 When the
> exception was thrown, this was the stack
> #0      double.parse (dart:core-patch/double_patch.dart:111:28)
> #1      _DeviceDataState.build. lib\componants\device_data.dart:160

the value for currentValue and sensorData when the app start is as follow:

I/flutter (25023): currentValue

I/flutter (25023):

I/flutter (25023): sensorData

I/flutter (25023): [ ]

and then when the app is connected to ESP32 is as follow:

I/flutter (25023): current

I/flutter (25023): 363.00,363.00,363.00

I/flutter (25023): sensor

I/flutter (25023): [363.00, 363.00, 363.00]

so the invalid double is only in the beginning.

Comment: Have you tried this? `temperature = double.parse(sensorData[0]);` That is, remove the `''` and remove the `$`

Comment: What is `sensorData[0]`?  Is it a `String`?  A list of integers?  A list of byte values?  You say the format is "number,number,number".  What does that represent?  How should it be interpreted?

Comment: @jamesdlin list of integer

Comment: And what do they represent?  How should they be interpreted?  Please provide examples.

Comment: @jamesdlin the ESP32 send a string via bluetooth with this format num,num,num.
I receive them via stream and split then according to the , on sensorData. then I need to convert them to double

Comment: @h8moss I removed them, it didn't work

Comment: Can you provide an example of the string you receive?

Comment: @jamesdlin I updated the post, the problem is only in the beginning

Answer (score 2):

Use curly brackets. Without it, it considers only sensordata as the variable and [0] as a string.
`temperature = double.parse('${sensorData[0]}');`

Comment: I tried that it didn't work

Comment: Print sensorData[0] and please let us know the result

Answer (score 2):

It means that the value that `sensorData[0]` is returning doesn't contain a number or isn't a number. Possibly a null value, that cannot be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by checking for null like this:

```
if (sensorData[0].isNotEmpty && sensorData[0] != null)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me!

```
 value = double.tryParse(sensorData[0]) ?? 0;
```

Comment: This should be the right answer, as using .tryParse("") if the value us null or it is NaN then it will return null and wont brake your app

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string into a double,
double.parse()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 temperature = (sensorData[0]==''||sensorData[0]==null)?(0):(double.parse('$sensorData[0]'));
```